# Codeigniter: Index page creation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

My folder structure is as following

```
admin
__master
_______address_book
_______Users
_______Product
_______etc
__operations
_______register_orders
_______payments
_______etc
```

I have created controllers for address_book,users,products,register_orders, payments etc to reduce the complexity of each controller.

Now, how to handle index page request for **www.abc.com/admin** ?
I have created Admin controller in /controllers directory then other links like
**www.abc.com/admin/master/address_book** will not work.

How to handle both requests?
I would also like to know is there any way to handle each index page requests
eg:

```
www.abc.com/admin/
www.abc.com/admin/master/
www.abc.com/admin/operations/
```

Comment: Apparently, you neglected to read and follow the very concise [online CodeIgniter documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access each request with url like-

```
www.abc.com/admin/
www.abc.com/admin/master/
www.abc.com/admin/operations/
```

you have to use `codeigniter's` routing. And for routing there are a `config` file under `aplication/config` folder named `routes.php`. Add all your routes in this file. Suppose you want to access this url-

```
www.abc.com/admin/operations/
```

then you have to create a new route for this in the `route file`, like-

```
$route['admin/operations']  = 'admin/operations';
```

where in `$route` array index you have to mention what will be the url and the value against this index you have to mention the controller's `path` and also you can mention the controller's `function` name which will be invoked (for `index` function there no need for mentioning).

Comment: thanks khairul islam, I tried this one also. I have created a temporary public function in Login controller with public admin() function and in router I crated a new entry "$route['login/admin'] = 'admin';" still its not working :(

Comment: oh..it must be reversed. thanks Khairul islam, its working now. could you please tell suggest me a best practice to handle this kind of index page requests

Comment: because multi level folder controllers not working on CodeIgniter !

Comment: you're welcome! codeigniters user guide is a good resource for everyone, and for uri routing you can follow this- http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html. (v 2.x)

Comment: @DiegoMariani codeigniter supports multi level folder controllers since it's version 2.x or before.

Comment: sorry, was my mistake